# String parameter is act as pass by value. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Possible this question seems duplicate but I explored stackoverflow article but noone gives answer to question.

I am trying to understand string data type behave. As we know string is immutable and reference data type.

So when we are passing a reference type parameter and change value in calling method , we get changes intact in caller method like as below code. e.g. we have user object which is passing as argument to a method "show" and this method change the value of user object and we get updated value in main method.This is happening as user is reference type.

When we passed string data type which is also reference type and immutable to print method and change value , we do not get updated value of string variable in main method.

Why this is behaving different than user object.?

When we passed string with ref parameter , we get updated value in main method. Here it is behaving like pass by ref.

So, string behaves like pass by value by default but this is pass by reference indeed, Why?

```
public class test
{
    public void Show(User user)
    {
        user.id = 2;
        user.Name = "Change";
    }
    public void Print(string test)
    {
        test = "new name";
    }
}
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Main method

```
User user = new User { id = 1, Name = "New" };
        
test test = new test();
test.Show(user);

string name = "old name";
test.Print(name);
```

I read c-sharp-string this and most reply is stating that two variables are pointing to same location. so if it is, then change to one value should reflect in both places.

Comment: Because you are updating the `User` properties, but not the reference itself (which is still a value type). With `string` you are updating reference itself

Comment: First, `User` is *not* immutable. Second, your methods do different things. One modifies the *properties* of the `User` object; the other modifies the local copy of the string reference, not any of its properties (of which `string` has none). You can't expect the same behavior when you do different things.

Comment: @madreflection how test  is local as it is called from main with value "old name" same as user objects. how user is not local and test is local..can you differentiate both ?

Comment: *Ceci n'est pas une pipe.* The variable is not the object, only a reference to it. When you pass the variable, you make a copy of the reference, not the object. Also not a pipe.

Comment: @madreflection if passing variable make a copy of reference ..it should make a copy of string reference also...can you explain your thought in details...?

Comment: There's no distinction between those two things.

Comment: @madreflection how are you explaining different behavior string vs object pass by val/ref?

Comment: The difference in behavior is explained by the fact that the *types* are implemented differently. The language and the runtime are not treating them differently. `User`'s properties are mutable. In `Show`, you're changing the properties on the instance. `String` doesn't have any mutable properties. In `Print`, you're assigning a different string instance to the parameter (which is essentially a local variable).  The comparable, apples-to-apples thing to do in `Show` would instead be `user = new User();`.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood objects are just pointers so when you pass in an object as an argument you are essentially copying the address of the instance into the function. So when you change the parameters of the passed object you are changing the parameters of the original instance. Now if you want to edit an int that is being passed as an argument you need to use the `ref` keyword. Also it might be interesting how this:

```
public void Show(User user)
    {
        user.id = 2;
        user.Name = "Change";
        user = null;
    }
```

Will change the parameters of the object but the user object won't be set to null. That is because we are only changing our local pointer to the instance in memory instead of actually changing the pointer we passed. But if we passed this using the `ref` keyword this would set the original instance we had in main to null.

Answer (score -1):

I may think string is called reference type. Because in C# when there are two string with same values or you have two strings and copy the value of one string to another. I will logically be not copied, until unless you change the value of second string. The second string will point to the same location as the first one. And in the above program you passed string as a value (am i write in this? no keyword ref is used, string is by default reference type, but if it is passed in parameter like this, and value change in original string then how can you be able to avoid reference of string while passing it in the parameter. (String is logically called reference typed : recommending a book, Read in that with detail will give you more knowledge about string data type in strings chapter.)

Comment: Fundemental of programming with C#